# Defining classes within a module

Tags: ruby, oop

```
module Vehicle
  class Car < Wheeled
  end
end

module Vehicle
  class Bike < Wheeled
  end
end
```

What does this pattern of creating classes try to achieve is what I am not able to understand. What will be the disadvantage of doing this by including `Vehicle` as a module in the other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it this way keeps those classes namespaced under the `Vehicle` module:

```
Car.new
# => NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Car
Vehicle::Car.new
# => #<Vehicle::Car:0x0000123456>
```

This way, you could also have a separate `Car` class outside of the module, and the `Vehicle::Car` class will not interfere.

Comment: Thanks ! This is the way that is followed when we need two classes with same name. I did not find a new class with the same name being created, which forced me to wonder if there was any other reason. Please do let me know if you can think of some other reason for this.

Comment: The specific code you're using may not have a conflict, but suppose you use that code in a project that uses other third-party libraries. If you didn't namespace the classes, and one of those third-party libraries also happened to have a `Car` class not within a specific namespace, there would be issues.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern groups related in some way classes into separate namespace to achieve more logical application structure and avoid naming conflicts. Superclass-subclass is very different, though in your particular example it would be better to go this way, because Car and Bike are both kind of Vehicle, but there are lot of situation when this in not the case. For example, grouping all classes of  application in the single module is widely used.